# Obtain count of rows on matched field from other table with prior date

Tags: mysql

Table A and Table B contain dates and surname fields;
Table A has unique values table B can contain multiple surnames for dates

I require SQL that can return the date and surname from Table A and the count of surnames from Table B that match table A
but where the date on table B is earlier than the date on Table A the information to be inserted into Table C.

In the past I have used parameter queries in vba to achieve something similar I haven't quite mastered the sub query which is what I assume I will need?

```
    table A 
     date   surname
    01/01/2009  smith
    02/01/2009  brown
    03/01/2009  brown
    04/01/2009  smith
    04/01/2009  brown
    05/01/2009  allen
    06/01/2009  smith
    07/01/2009  wilson
    08/01/2009  bridge
    08/01/2009  smith


    Table B 
     date   surname
    01/01/2009  smith
    01/01/2009  brown
    01/01/2009  brown
    02/01/2009  brown
    02/01/2009  brown
    03/01/2009  brown
    04/01/2009  smith
    04/01/2009  smith
    04/01/2009  smith
    04/01/2009  brown
    04/01/2009  allen
    06/01/2009  allen
    06/01/2009  allen
    07/01/2009  allen
    07/01/2009  wilson
    07/01/2009  wilson
    07/01/2009  wilson
    07/01/2009  wilson
    07/01/2009  wilson
    08/01/2009  wilson
    08/01/2009  bridge

    Table c     
     date   surname count
    01/01/2009  smith   0
    02/01/2009  brown   2
    03/01/2009  brown   4
    04/01/2009  smith   1
    04/01/2009  brown   5
    05/01/2009  allen   1
    06/01/2009  smith   4
    07/01/2009  wilson  0
    08/01/2009  bridge  0
    08/01/2009  smith   4
```

Comment: can you provide table structure and some demo how you want the response?

Comment: Table A date,surname Table B date surname    Table C   date surname count

Comment: if there are no entries in table B for the surname prior to the date provided in table a then a zero count will be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables with your conditions and aggregate:

```
create table TableC as
select a.date, a.surname, count(b.date)
from TableA a left join TableB b
on b.surname = a.surname and b.date < a.date
group by a.date, a.surname;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uojJtn9iSQ8LfeXKzpzVfx/1).
Results:

```
| date       | surname | count |
| ---------- | ------- | ----- |
| 2009-01-01 | smith   | 0     |
| 2009-02-01 | brown   | 2     |
| 2009-03-01 | brown   | 4     |
| 2009-04-01 | brown   | 5     |
| 2009-04-01 | smith   | 1     |
| 2009-05-01 | allen   | 1     |
| 2009-06-01 | smith   | 4     |
| 2009-07-01 | wilson  | 0     |
| 2009-08-01 | bridge  | 0     |
| 2009-08-01 | smith   | 4     |
```

Comment: Forpas thanks that worked I thought I would need to write a subquery! If Table B had an additional field called VIP and I only wanted to include records in the count where VIP field was = to 1 would I need to change much to this SQL?

Comment: The ON clause should be: `on b.surname = a.surname and b.date < a.date and b.VIP = 1`.

Comment: Hi Forpas adding and b.VIP = 1 didn't work in access sql I needed to add a where clause. Thanks for the initial solution.

Comment: @Madbeagle Access is not the same as MySql. It does not support such conditions in the ON clause. If you added the condition in the WHERE clause then the join is changed to an INNER join which means that it will not return unmatched rows.